# I need to put my image container on the left and my bundle options on the right

Tags: html, css

I have two containers, one with an image and the other with the product bundle options. I need them to be side by side, the image on the left and the bundle on the right, but I'm not getting it.

I was trying here and this was my code., i have some scripts too to make the bundle functional but i can't put the image on the left and the bundles on the right

```css
.productname2 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.checkboxtest {
  max-width: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.checkboxtest+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.productname {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.image-container {
  width: 488px;
  height: 488px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: #252a32;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.bundle-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.bundle-header {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.bundle-header-1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.bundle-header-2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.bundle-options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bundle-option {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bundle-option.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #f45b69;
  color: #f45b69;
}

.bundle-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.bundle-save {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.add-to-cart {
  background-color: #f45b69;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}


/* teste de css pro 2 container */

.bundle-container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.bundle-container-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.bundle-header-2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.bundle-options-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bundle-option-2 {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bundle-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.bundle-save {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bundle-option input[type="checkbox"] {
  float: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.bundle-option label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="" alt="Product Image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="bundle-container-1">
        <label for="bundle1" class="bundle-header-1">Choose your bundle:</label>
        <div id="container1" class="bundle-options">
          <div class="bundle-option active" data-months="3" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle1-0" name="ch" value="0" class="checkboxtest" data-texto="Texto 1">
            <label for="bundle1-0" class="productname">3 Month Supply -<br>6x Micro-Infusion Treatments</label>
          </div>
          <div class="bundle-option" data-months="6" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle2-0" name="ch" value="1" class="checkboxtest" data-texto="Texto 2">
            <label for="bundle2-0" class="productname">2 Month Supply -<br>4x Micro-Infusion Treatments</label>
          </div>
          <div class="bundle-option" data-months="12" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle3-0" name="ch" value="2" class="checkboxtest">
            <label for="bundle3-0" class="productname">1 Month Supply -<br>2x Micro-Infusion Treatments</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bundle-footer">
          <div id="footer">
            <span id="texto1"></span>
            <span id="texto2"></span>
            <span id="texto3"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bundle-container-2">
        <label for="bundle2" class="bundle-header-2">Choose your serums:</label>
        <div class="bundle-options">
          <div class="bundle-option active" data-months="3" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle4-0" name="ch" value="4" class="checkboxtest">
            <label for="bundle4-0" class="productname">Rejuvenating Serum</label>
          </div>
          <div class="bundle-option" data-months="6" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle5-0" name="ch" class="checkboxtest">
            <label for="bundle5-0" class="productname">Hydra-Soothing Serum</label>
          </div>
          <div class="bundle-option" data-months="12" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle6-0" name="ch" value="5" class="checkboxtest">
            <label for="bundle6-0" class="productname2"><br>Both Serums</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `container`, `row`, `col-` classes seem reminiscent of [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), so you could add Bootstrap to layout your DOM:

```css
.productname2 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.checkboxtest {
  max-width: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.checkboxtest+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.productname {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.image-container {
  width: 488px;
  height: 488px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: #252a32;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.bundle-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.bundle-header {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.bundle-header-1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.bundle-header-2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.bundle-options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bundle-option {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bundle-option.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #f45b69;
  color: #f45b69;
}

.bundle-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.bundle-save {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.add-to-cart {
  background-color: #f45b69;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}


/* teste de css pro 2 container */

.bundle-container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.bundle-container-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.bundle-header-2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.bundle-options-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bundle-option-2 {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bundle-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.bundle-save {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bundle-option input[type="checkbox"] {
  float: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.bundle-option label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="" alt="Product Image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="bundle-container-1">
        <label for="bundle1" class="bundle-header-1">Choose your bundle:</label>
        <div id="container1" class="bundle-options">
          <div class="bundle-option active" data-months="3" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle1-0" name="ch" value="0" class="checkboxtest" data-texto="Texto 1">
            <label for="bundle1-0" class="productname">3 Month Supply -<br>6x Micro-Infusion Treatments</label>
          </div>
          <div class="bundle-option" data-months="6" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle2-0" name="ch" value="1" class="checkboxtest" data-texto="Texto 2">
            <label for="bundle2-0" class="productname">2 Month Supply -<br>4x Micro-Infusion Treatments</label>
          </div>
          <div class="bundle-option" data-months="12" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle3-0" name="ch" value="2" class="checkboxtest">
            <label for="bundle3-0" class="productname">1 Month Supply -<br>2x Micro-Infusion Treatments</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bundle-footer">
          <div id="footer">
            <span id="texto1"></span>
            <span id="texto2"></span>
            <span id="texto3"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bundle-container-2">
        <label for="bundle2" class="bundle-header-2">Choose your serums:</label>
        <div class="bundle-options">
          <div class="bundle-option active" data-months="3" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle4-0" name="ch" value="4" class="checkboxtest">
            <label for="bundle4-0" class="productname">Rejuvenating Serum</label>
          </div>
          <div class="bundle-option" data-months="6" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle5-0" name="ch" class="checkboxtest">
            <label for="bundle5-0" class="productname">Hydra-Soothing Serum</label>
          </div>
          <div class="bundle-option" data-months="12" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle6-0" name="ch" value="5" class="checkboxtest">
            <label for="bundle6-0" class="productname2"><br>Both Serums</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Otherwise, the bare minimum would be initiating a horizontal flex layout on the `.row` element:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
.productname2 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.checkboxtest {
  max-width: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.checkboxtest+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.productname {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.image-container {
  width: 488px;
  height: 488px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: #252a32;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.bundle-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.bundle-header {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.bundle-header-1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.bundle-header-2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.bundle-options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bundle-option {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bundle-option.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #f45b69;
  color: #f45b69;
}

.bundle-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.bundle-save {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.add-to-cart {
  background-color: #f45b69;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}


/* teste de css pro 2 container */

.bundle-container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.bundle-container-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.bundle-header-2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.bundle-options-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bundle-option-2 {
  width: 33.33%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bundle-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.bundle-save {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bundle-option input[type="checkbox"] {
  float: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.bundle-option label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="" alt="Product Image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="bundle-container-1">
        <label for="bundle1" class="bundle-header-1">Choose your bundle:</label>
        <div id="container1" class="bundle-options">
          <div class="bundle-option active" data-months="3" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle1-0" name="ch" value="0" class="checkboxtest" data-texto="Texto 1">
            <label for="bundle1-0" class="productname">3 Month Supply -<br>6x Micro-Infusion Treatments</label>
          </div>
          <div class="bundle-option" data-months="6" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle2-0" name="ch" value="1" class="checkboxtest" data-texto="Texto 2">
            <label for="bundle2-0" class="productname">2 Month Supply -<br>4x Micro-Infusion Treatments</label>
          </div>
          <div class="bundle-option" data-months="12" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle3-0" name="ch" value="2" class="checkboxtest">
            <label for="bundle3-0" class="productname">1 Month Supply -<br>2x Micro-Infusion Treatments</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bundle-footer">
          <div id="footer">
            <span id="texto1"></span>
            <span id="texto2"></span>
            <span id="texto3"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bundle-container-2">
        <label for="bundle2" class="bundle-header-2">Choose your serums:</label>
        <div class="bundle-options">
          <div class="bundle-option active" data-months="3" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle4-0" name="ch" value="4" class="checkboxtest">
            <label for="bundle4-0" class="productname">Rejuvenating Serum</label>
          </div>
          <div class="bundle-option" data-months="6" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle5-0" name="ch" class="checkboxtest">
            <label for="bundle5-0" class="productname">Hydra-Soothing Serum</label>
          </div>
          <div class="bundle-option" data-months="12" data-image="" data-url="">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bundle6-0" name="ch" value="5" class="checkboxtest">
            <label for="bundle6-0" class="productname2"><br>Both Serums</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```